# Continuity of two variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I've got the following exercise and I need some help trying to figure out what's a proper way of proving it:
Take the function $$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},  & \text{if $x^2+y^2<1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x^2+y^2\ge1$}
\end{cases}
$$

And the question, is prove that the function is continuous on $ R^2 $

Is it enough to say that if you plug $x^2+y^2=1$ (which are the only set points where discontinuity could happen) on both equations and see that they both equal to zero, it means that the function will be continuous at those points because the limit is always zero no matter where you approach it from?

Comment: In this case you are right. But a *plug-in* method perhaps won't work in general (for example when the set of questionable points isn't in a regular shape). So it's best that you try to prove it from definition, which should not be hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to show $$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to 1^-} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} = 0$$

For this purpose, we can use polar coordinates and set

$$x = r \cdot \cos \theta$$
$$y = r \cdot \sin \theta$$

Thus we get

$$\lim_{r^2( \cos^2 \theta+ \sin^2 \theta) \to 1^-} \sqrt{1-r^2(\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta)}$$

Since $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$, we have

$$\lim_{r^2\to 1^-} \sqrt{1-r^2} = \lim_{s\to 1^-} \sqrt{1-s}= 0$$

Thus, $f(x,y)$ is continous.